# Eliminar la particion de Windows 10 y aumentar la particion linux

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 20.04, hard-drive

you can translate with the translator if you want

Tengo Ubuntu instalado y Windows 10 también  en un HDD de 1TB, 900G para Windows y 100G para Ubuntu, debido a que me quedo **sin espacio** y el **Windows 10 esta roto y no funciona**

> Quiero quitar la partición del Windows 10 y darle todo el espacio disponible a Ubuntu

para ello usare Partition Magic

**-- ENGLISH--**

I have Ubuntu installed and Windows 10 also on a 1TB HDD, 900G for Windows and 100G for Ubuntu, because I run out of space and Windows 10 is broken and does not work

I want to remove the partition from Windows 10 and give all available space to Ubuntu

for this I will use Partition Magic

Comment: Please, you could translate (using an online translator, if you feel more comfortable with it) by yourself and then [edit] your question. You can keep the original Spanish question alongside the English one.

Comment: Partition Magic is a tool focused on Windows. Don’t stick to it if you want to leave Windows. [GParted](https://gparted.org/) is your new Partition Magic!

Comment: Yeah, I'm flashing the UBUNTU 20.04 iso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gparted, delete the partition corresponding to MS Windows and create a new one in ext4 format, do not delete UEFI partitions if any, only the one from MS Windows.

Then move your / home to this partition.

Suppose de new home is /dev/sda3

Open a terminal and run:

```
exec sudo -i
mkdir /media/hometemp
mount /dev/sda3 /media/hometemp
cd /home
cp -ax . /media/hometemp
cd /
mv /home /home.old
mkdir /home
umount /dev/sda3
mount /dev/sda3 /home
exit
```

If everything works, add the UUID in /etc/fstab to /dev/sda3.

```
exec sudo -i
blkid /dev/sda3
gedit /etc/fstab
```

You must add the lines at the bottom of the file to mount your new /home directory

```
Type the UUUI of the partition at the start of the line, (UUID= sda3 UUID) and then press Tab.

Type the mount point, /home,  and press Tab.

Type the filesystem description ext4, and press Tab.

Type defaults for the mount options, and press Tab.

Type the digit 0 for the filesystem dump option, and press Tab.

Type the digit 0 for the filesystem check option.
```

Save the fstab file, close Gedit and reboot.

Once you’re perfectly sure that you no longer need the safety copy of your old /home directory, you can delete it:

```
cd /
sudo rm -rf home.old/
```

Comment: Sorry, but I did it now,in another medium, and I expanded the / partition Because if I use 800g for /home, 100g is for programs and libraries